# script.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: serachFor is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, global-variables, var

Why is my variable not defined?  I defined it as a global variable at the start but this is not recognised in my function.

script.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: serachFor is not defined

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var searchFor = "";
var artists = "js/data.json";

$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.getJSON( artists, function(data) {
        searchFor = $('#search').val();
        $.each( data, function( i, item ) {
            if (serachFor == item.name) {
                $("ul").append( "<li>Name: " + item.name + 
                                "<br/>Known: " + item.reknown + 
                                "<br/><img src='images/" + item.shortname + "_tn.jpg' />" + 
                                "<br/>Bio: " + item.bio + "</li><hr/>" );
            }  // end of if statement
       }); // end of each function 
    }); // end of getJson function 
  });  // end of submit on click function 
});  // end document ready function
```

Comment: Doesn't the error message tell it all: `serachFor !== searchFor`.

Answer (score 0):

You typed in "serach" instead of search.

Thanks to @Teemu for spotting this one, I didn't see that you used it multiple times.

Comment: @Jacqueline We all misspell things sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare your global variable outside of the $(document).ready(function(){...});

You are not actually creating a global variable if you put it inside of the doc ready function.

```
/* Global Variables */    
var searchFor = "";

$(document).ready(function() {...});
```

You also mispelled searchFor as serachFor